# can't find symbol error, java

Tags: java

I declared a global vector, and I'm trying to access it globally, but it throws an error.

It says cannot find symbol XArray or YArray.

The code I'm using (I've cut some of it out that I thought was not necessary):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String csvFile = "/Users/hherzberg/Desktop/testData.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        ArrayList<Point3D> myPoints = new ArrayList<Point3D>();
        ArrayList<Double>  XArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> YArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
        try {
            int xcount=0;
            int ycount=0;

            double multiplied=0;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            br.readLine();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // use comma as separator
                String[] number = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                double x = Double.parseDouble(number[0]);
                double y = Double.parseDouble(number[1]);
                XArray.add(x);
                YArray.add(y);
                Point3D p = new Point3D(x, y);
                myPoints.add(p);
                xcount+=1;
                ycount+=1;

                System.out.println(p);
            }
            for (int i=0; i<myPoints.size();i++)
            {
                multiplied+=Double.parseDouble(XArray(i))*Double.parseDouble(YArray(i+1));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Some help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the necessary imports for `BufferedReader` and `ArrayList`. Some remarks: a) your should really format your code properly, your indentation is messy b) in Java, variable names should always start with a lowercase letter c) `XArray` and `YArray` are not global variables, they are local variabled d) your vocabulary is off, `XArray` and `YArray` are neither arrays, nor `Vector`s, they are `List`s, backed by an array and e) starting a question with "Yo" is a little bit inappropriate.

Comment: `XArray(i)`: Either you have a method which you're not showing us, or you should read the JavaDoc about getting a value from a list.

Comment: Can you point in the code what are the lines throwing the errors you mention?

Answer (score 0):

Use below import at first line and it should work

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
```